# Revise the permission modal alert to specify why the app is requesting access to the users location

Tags: ios

We need the user location when user some action perform,Why appleReview team is saying like this
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your `Usage Description` key for location in `Info.plist` probably empty, add some description to it

Comment: if Usage Description will be empty then Location Model alert will not be show see the edited question.

Comment: You need to provide a location usage description that is a complete and clear English sentence. For example "This will allow *yourappname* to locate your nearest *BusinessName*". Also, you should not ask for location permission until the user first accesses a function that requires it. The login screen in probably not the right time. When they click a "find my nearest..." button is. The location permission request needs to be clear and in context.

Comment: Tank You @Paulw11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to describe in alert model why you are taking location in this app

example:
[image]

//This will Allow to you Place Order If Your Location Does Match to Restaurent Location

Answer (score 0):

Lol you put like that no wonder get app rejected, put clear description why you need location for.

Example: `Please provide location to locate nearest bar.`

Comment: i relied the description why we need to location then rejected again.